# Await Angular JS in a service (REST -> $resource)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, async-await, promise, angular-resource

There are a lot of topic on the internet about this topic. But still I'm stuck.
Because of all the information I can't see the threes in the forest anymore (Dutch saying)

Hope to get some help this way. I'm really sorry if this is a duplicate!
I'm mainly a C# developer but wanted to learn some Web frameworks. I started @ AngularJS. This is my first bigger project. So I'm still a newbie when it comes to AngularJS

I'm making a kind of a DAL (yeah C#). I use a service for this. My purpose ofcourse is encapsulating the rest calls for my controllers!

```
angular.module("adminApp").service("adminRestDAL", function ($resource, $q) {
var userData;

this.getUsers = function () {
    if (!userData)
        userData = $resource("/admin/users").query();
    return userData;
};
```

So here is my function to get all my users. I used 'caching', I don't reload all my users. In my application it's not needed. As a result it's much more smoother! (less waiting)

Now my problem is I want to load all my answers. I add the username to my answers with the aid of their userid. I'd like to use my local list (cached one)...

```
this.getAnswers = function () {
    //Always update answers!
    //No need for manuel caching (no global variable)

    //Make sure we have our users loaded!
    //This is exactly why I <3 C#
    //I could reuse my existing function (getUsers) and just put 'await' before it...
    this.getUsers();

    var answersData = $resource("/admin/answers").query(function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (answer) {
            answer.name = userData.find(function (u) {
                return u._id === answer.userid;
            }).name;
        });
    });
    return answersData;
};
```

Check the comments. I have to wait until users is loaded to continue. In 80% of the case this function works. The users are done before the answers and then there no problem. But when it's not, userData is undefined and my answers will have no username...

I tried a lot. And this was my final solution (that doens't work). I made a separate function that return the promise of the query

```
function getUsersAsync() {
    if (!userData)
        return $resource("/admin/users").query().$promise
            .then(
                function (success) {
                    userData = success;
                })

};

this.getAnswers = function () {
    //Always update answers!
    //No need for manuel caching (no global variable)

    //Make sure we have our users loaded!
    //This is exactly why I <3 C#
    //I could reuse my existing function (getUsers) and just put 'await' before it...
    //this.getUsers();

    getUsersAsync().then(
        function()
        {
            var answersData = $resource("/admin/answers").query(function (data) {
                data.forEach(function (answer) {
                    answer.name = userData.find(function (u) {
                        return u._id === answer.userid;
                    }).name;
                });
            });
            return answersData;
        }
    )
};
```

Here the 'code' waits until my users are loaded. But I'm not able to return my data (answers) anymore! The return is now for another function than my getAnswers() function...

So I don't know how to solve this problem in AngularJS. I searched a lot and found some usefull blogs. But still stuck. I also found that ES7 is coming with Await and Async keywords...

If you have tips to solve this, or to make it better. You would really help me out!

If there is something wrong with my 'architecture' also let me know, like I said my first time in AngularJS. I'm want to learn :)

Sincerely, ErazerBrecht

Answer (score 1):

Use the original `$promise` and **chain** from that.

```
this.getAnswers = function () {

    var answersData = $resource("/admin/answers").query();

    //save promise for chaining
    var secondPromise = answersData.$promise.then( function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (answer) {
            answer.name = userData.find(function (u) {
                return u._id === answer.userid;
            }).name;
        });
    });
    //return secondPromise for chaining    
    answersData.$promise2 = secondPromise;
    return answersData;
};
```

In your client code, **chain** from the second promise.

```
var refinedAnswers = getAnswers();

refinedAnswers.$promise2.then (function onFulfilled() {
    console.log(refinedAnswers);
};
```

For more information on **chaining** see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- chaining](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).

Comment: Didn't now that. I read it and there some places in my project where I could use it! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be trying to combine your user and answers data in the service.  The service is merely the encapsulation that grabs the data - it's the controller that should be combining the data so that it's available to your view in an efficient format.

With this in mind, your service should be bare bones simple:

```
this.getUsers = function(){
    return $resource("/admin/users").query();
};

this.getAnswers = function(){
    return $resource("/admin/answers").query();
};
```

Then, in your controller, is where you would piece together your caching logic.

```
$scope.users = null;

$scope.getUsers = function(){
    if($scope.users === null){
        myService.getUsers().$promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.users = data;
        });
    }
});

$scope.getAnswers = function(){
    myService.getAnswers().$promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.answers = data;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.answers.length; i++){
            $scope.answers[i].name = $scope.users.find(function(u){
                    return u._id === $scope.answers[i].userid;
            }).name;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Originally I had something like that!
But I had to add the usernames on multiple controllers. And I didn't like the duplicated code.

Is there a reason why I shouldn't do it in the service.
Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: @ErazerBrecht In this case, you should separate out the caching logic for `getUsers` and `getAnswers` into its own controller.  Remember you can have multiple controllers on a page.  This way, anytime you need the two functions, you could just bring in their controller.  Following this paradigm, you'll have a nice separation of your controllers /  models.

Answer (score 0):

Always when I post something to Stackoverflow I find the answer myself a couple minutes later. I should pause a bit.

I forgot to try to execute my getUser functionality in the callback of my getAnwsers resource. This did solve my problem.

Nevertheless thanks to the two guys who answered! You are the reason why stackoverflow is a good place for someone new who is learning stuff :)

```
//Private function
//Had to do this because if need to access this function inside a callback
//this doesn't point to this service anymore but to the callback...
function getUsersAsync() {
    if (!userData)
        userData = $resource("/admin/users").query();
    return userData;
};

this.getUsers = function () {
    return getUsersAsync();
};

this.getAnswers = function () {
    //Always update answers!
    //No need for manuel caching (no global variable)

    var answersData = $resource("/admin/answers").query(function (data) {
        //Make sure we have our users loaded!
        getUsersAsync().$promise
            .then(
                function () {
                    data.forEach(function (answer) {
                        answer.name = userData.find(function (u) {
                            return u._id === answer.userid;
                        }).name;
                    });
                }
            )
    });
    return answersData;
};
```